# How do you specify request body attributes in Apiary.io / API Blueprint?

Tags: markdown, apiblueprint, apiary.io

I'm trying to figure out how to describe/define the request body attributes/parameters for POST/PUT. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation (I wish there was a way to view the markdown of any public Apiary doc): http://docs.bynder.apiary.io/#reference/metaproperties/metaproperty-access/save-new-metaproperty

See the description and attribute definitions under the "Request" section? How do I do that?

Comment: When I click `API Blueprint` in the header, I get [this](https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/bynder.apib) in a new tab.

Comment: How in the world did I miss that... Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is how they have probably done it. Please take a look at the API Blueprint specification at https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint to know more.

```
+ Request (application/json)

    You can have any description here. This is based on markdown.

    + Even a list
    + `name` Name of the metaproperty, should be alphanumeric only. Uneditable.

    + Body

            {
              "name": "app"
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. Personally, I find the API Blueprint spec/docs quite unintuitive.